# Finding the definition of a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I need to get the values of the members of a struct (in my case it's a `GLFWwindow` struct), but since the struct is only defined in the header file, I don't know what members it has. I need to know the members to access them and get the values though.

How would I go about finding what members the struct has and how they're called?

Comment: Why do you need to access the data in the struct? It seems it’s an opaque struct and I’m sure there is a reason. What data do you need from there that you can’t get otherwise?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I want to return the value of the struct back to python (I am building a Python C extension).

Comment: There is no way to recover structure members from an **incomplete** structure definition. Normally structs are keep opaque when direct access is not desired. If you have legitimate reasons to access the struct, you must include in your source the internal header where the structure is defined.

Comment: @Frankie_C, that seems to me to be the whole answer. Post as an answer?

Comment: Actually python offers a way to pass pointers around, which I was unaware of at the time of asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using Python's [PyCapsule](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/capsule.html). At first I thought this problem's solution would be regarding C and thus didn't mention Python in the question. In the end I found that this question has to do with Python and that's why I am writing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the definition from GCC.

```
gcc -E somefilewithinclude.c | less
/symbolname
```

If you only ever have `struct GLFWwindow;` you can't do this but must pass pointers to it. Incomplete structures can only ever have pointers to them.